# Oculus Rift CV1 Black Display

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, hdmi, oculus-runtime

I recently bough my brand new CV1. Even though My GTX 980M is not recommended VGA but it should display something. Now about the problem. It started with Oculus Home setup, seem to everything worked fine, even tracking is working, I listened audio from setup process but display was completely black. And LED is orange btw. However I managed to pass settings using audio only with my Oculus remote. Now i can see the Oculus Home, but when I try to run any app from there it simply stays black. I am also a Unity3D developer and when I tried to launch my own apps same happened. In unity HDM is working, gyro is ok (I can see on my laptop display when I'm turning around) but display is still black, with orange LED light. And here some Oculus server logs I've been captured maybe it can help! Please Help anybody!

```
24/08 15:36:48.824 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] motionSensorEvent() Start
24/08 15:36:48.824 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] HMD Moving: true
24/08 15:36:48.824 {INFO}    [TrackingManager] Setting tracking mode to on
24/08 15:36:48.824 {INFO}    [Server] Tracking Enabled : true
24/08 15:36:48.824 {DEBUG}   [Server] UpdateFocusedVirtualHmd: ConfigureTracking On (112)
24/08 15:36:48.824 {DEBUG}   [Kernel:Default] [VirtualHMD] Applying client-specific caps
24/08 15:36:48.825 {WARNING} [Server] Setting connection focus to pid: 1336, file: oculus-overlays.exe, but no window handle exists
24/08 15:36:48.825 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] motionSensorEvent() End
24/08 15:36:49.118 {INFO}    [HW:Enumeration] HMDs: 1, Displays: 1
24/08 15:36:49.118 {DEBUG}   [HW:HmdSensor] IMU report rate = 500
24/08 15:36:49.118 {INFO}    [HW:HmdSensor] Leaving idle mode
24/08 15:36:49.118 {INFO}    [HW:Enumeration] Setting frameInterval = 19200, ledExposure = 399
24/08 15:36:49.118 {INFO}    [HW:HmdSensor] Setting LED state: true
24/08 15:36:49.320 {DEBUG}   [Server] Connection open for pid: 12020, file: Unity.exe
24/08 15:36:49.320 {DEBUG}   [Server] Accepted a client from pid: 12020(Unity.exe) running version (prod = 1).1.7.0(build = 262766) feature version = 0. Server is version (prod = 1).1.7.0(build = 262766) feature version = 0
24/08 15:36:49.321 {DEBUG}   [Server] UpdateFocusedVirtualHmd: ConfigureTracking On (112)
24/08 15:36:49.321 {DEBUG}   [Kernel:Default] [VirtualHMD] Applying client-specific caps
24/08 15:36:50.450 {WARNING} [Server] Setting connection focus to pid: 1336, file: oculus-overlays.exe, but no window handle exists
24/08 15:36:50.450 {DEBUG}   [Server] Hmd_Create
24/08 15:36:50.450 {DEBUG}   [Kernel:Default] [AppFocusObserver] AddProcess: Recognizing the newly added process as in-focus pid=12020
24/08 15:36:50.450 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] registerPid() Start
24/08 15:36:50.450 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Register Pid: 12020 (Sideloaded)
24/08 15:36:50.450 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Registering tracker: 12020 (Sideloaded)
24/08 15:36:50.450 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] App already added.
24/08 15:36:50.450 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] registerPid() End
24/08 15:36:50.450 {DEBUG}   [Server] Hmd_GetHmdInfo
24/08 15:36:50.454 {DEBUG}   [Kernel:Default] [AppFocusObserver] UpdateTextureSetActive: Setting rift window for pid=12020 textureset=1
24/08 15:36:50.454 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] requestFocus() Start
24/08 15:36:50.454 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Request Focus: 12020 (Sideloaded)
24/08 15:36:50.454 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Request Location: APP
24/08 15:36:50.454 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Push Location: APP
24/08 15:36:50.454 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Update Location: HSW
24/08 15:36:50.454 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Inactive Focus: 3452 (oculus-home)
24/08 15:36:50.454 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Already Focused: 0 (Unknown)
24/08 15:36:50.454 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] requestFocus() End
24/08 15:36:50.455 {INFO}    [Kernel:Default] WARNING: [CameraTimeSynchronizer] out of sync. Exposure Delta = 33830.2 ms, cameraDelta = -32430.4 ms.
24/08 15:36:50.455 {WARNING} [Tracking:Tracker] WMTD302S600Z3S: at 0, skipped 1 frames (37403 -> 37405)
24/08 15:36:50.569 {INFO}    [Kernel:Default] [CameraTimeSynchronizer] successfully synchronized.
24/08 15:36:50.667 {DEBUG}   [Tracking:Filter] HMD: Large change, resetting position filter
24/08 15:36:51.031 {INFO}    [DeviceEvent] SENSOR [WMTD302S600Z3S] TrackingChanged 0 
24/08 15:36:51.031 {INFO}    [HardwareManager] Tracker WMTD302S600Z3S got tracking event with error code 0
24/08 15:36:51.518 {DEBUG}   [Kernel:Default] [AppFocusObserver] UpdateRenderingActive: pid=12020 active
24/08 15:36:51.518 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] enterVR() Start
24/08 15:36:51.518 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Enter VR: 12020 (Sideloaded)
24/08 15:36:51.518 {INFO}    [AppTracker] VR Ready: 12020 (Sideloaded)
24/08 15:36:51.518 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Request Focus: 12020 (Sideloaded)
24/08 15:36:51.518 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Request Location: APP
24/08 15:36:51.518 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Push Location: APP
24/08 15:36:51.518 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Update Location: HSW
24/08 15:36:51.519 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Inactive Focus: 3452 (oculus-home)
24/08 15:36:51.519 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Already Focused: 0 (Unknown)
24/08 15:36:51.519 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] enterVR() End
24/08 15:36:54.815 {DEBUG}   [Tracking:Pnp] RansacMatch: Too many outliers: 1 outliers out of 5, allowed 0
24/08 15:36:58.592 {DEBUG}   [Kernel:Default] [AppFocusObserver] UpdateTextureSetActive: Active process pid=12020 dismantling its last texture set
24/08 15:36:58.592 {DEBUG}   [Kernel:Default] [AppFocusObserver] NextProcess: Switching active rift process to pid=1336 textureset=1 (not updating active render window)
24/08 15:36:58.592 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] requestFocus() Start
24/08 15:36:58.592 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Request Focus: 1336 (oculus-overlays)
24/08 15:36:58.592 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] Setting focus to Overlays is not allowed.
24/08 15:36:58.592 {INFO}    [LifeCycle] requestFocus() End
24/08 15:36:58.594 {DEBUG}   [Server] UpdateFocusedVirtualHmd: ConfigureTracking On (112)
24/08 15:36:58.594 {DEBUG}   [Kernel:Default] [VirtualHMD] Applying client-specific caps
24/08 15:36:58.598 {WARNING} [Server] Setting connection focus to pid: 1336, file: oculus-overlays.exe, but no window handle exists
24/08 15:36:58.598 {INFO}    [Server] Connection closed for pid: 12020, file: Unity.exe
24/08 15:36:58.598 {DEBUG}   [Server] UpdateFocusedVirtualHmd: ConfigureTracking On (112)
24/08 15:36:58.598 {DEBUG}   [Kernel:Default] [VirtualHMD] Applying client-specific caps
24/08 15:36:58.616 {WARNING} [Server] Setting connection focus to pid: 1336, file: oculus-overlays.exe, but no window handle exists
24/08 15:36:58.616 {INFO}    [Server] Connection destroyed for pid: 12020, file: Unity.exe
24/08 15:37:01.456 {INFO}    [DeviceEvent] SENSOR [WMTD302S600Z3S] TrackingChanged 0 
24/08 15:37:01.456 {INFO}    [HardwareManager] Tracker WMTD302S600Z3S got tracking event with error code 0
```

Comment: This should be asked on the Oculus forums or on Super User.  Unless you're writing software using the Oculus SDK and getting a black screen with your own app, this is not the right place to ask.

Comment: While not on topic, I had the same issue - try to change the USB port, possibly this one doesn't give enough power.

Comment: It doesn't only happens to my app, Oculus Home is also shows black screen with audio. I Tried to switch between 2 of my usb3 ports but no difference :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few days I've figured out the problem. Despite ASUS ROG G751 doesn't have a Optimus technology enabled, its HDMI port is still connected something intel GPU related. Thats why rift is not getting enough performance and stays black. I tried bunch of adapters from thunderbolt (Mini Display Port) and VGA. Nothing worked out. Then I read server logs from Oculus and there was one saying Not enough bandwidth. I understood that problem is something related to adapter performance so I used 4k capable Mini Displayport to HDMI adapter (link below) and voliah!! Rift is working! No lags or any other problems! Just try 4K enabled adapter!

Here is a working adapter - [https://www.amazon.com/Macally-Aluminum-DisplayPort-Thunderbolt-MDHDMI4K/dp/B013H07SX6/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1472844784&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=macally+mdp+hdmi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013H07SX6)

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I learned that my HDMI isnt giving a strong enough output and I have experimented with a couple different products that helps add power to the rift!

HTC Vive Link Box [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LXR6DKV?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LXR6DKV)

AC to DC 12V Power Supply Adapter... [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01GPXNJPI?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GPXNJPI)

UGREEN USB 3.0 A to A Cable Type... [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00P0E3954?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00P0E3954)

These three products allowed the oculus rift to run on a laptop when no display and only a orange light was on in the headset, Now everything is running fine! Thank you so much for your time and please suggest these products to people if they are having the same issue I am and if the troubleshooting isnt working.